# Prevent Laravel to merge global default reply-to email when specifying Email on the Mail class

Tags: laravel

The mail.php configuration comes with this setting:

```
'reply_to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_REPLY_TO_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_REPLY_TO_NAME', 'Example')
    ],
```

It works well, but let say you want to use a different reply-to email for a certain Mail,  so you do this in your Mail class:

```
->replyTo('mymail@gmail.com');
```

What Laravel 9 does is to merge both emails, the global reply-to and the one you just specified.

How can I prevent this behavior? If I specify an e-mail, I don't want Laravel to merge it with the global default.

Any idea? Thanks.